# Loop not completing full code in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have made a number guessing game yet when I run it the loop only loops the

```
guess = raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 50: ")
```

so I was wondering if anyone knew a fix. The full code is listed below:

```
import random
score = 1000
print "Welcome to this number guessing game!"
number = random.randint(1, 50)
while True:
    guess = raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 50: ")
if guess == number:
    print "You got it right!"
    print "Your score was:" + score
    quit()
if guess < number:
    print "Too Big"
    score = score - 10
if guess > number:
    print "Too Small"
    score = score - 10
```

Comment: `guess = raw_input(...)` is the only statement that's indented underneath the while loop.  So that statement runs over and over, and the loop never exits.

Comment: Also, check the comparisons (`string` vs `int`) and your `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You want to indent your code properly to let the interpreter know what is inside the loop:

```
import random
score = 1000
print "Welcome to this number guessing game!"
number = random.randint(1, 50)
while True:
    guess = raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 50: ")
    if guess == number:
        print "You got it right!"
        print "Your score was:" + score
        quit()
    if guess < number:
        print "Too Big"
        score = score - 10
    if guess > number:
        print "Too Small"
        score = score - 10
```

Answer (score 0):

AndreyS got it right, but you're comparing different types and thus not getting the expected output.

Here's a simple example of your game working:

```
import random
score = 1000
print "Welcome to this number guessing game!"
number = random.randint(1, 50)
while True:
    guess = raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 50: ")
    if int(guess) == number:
        print "You got it right!"
        print "Your score was:" + str(score)
        quit()
    if int(guess) > number:
        print "Too Big"
        score = score - 10
    if int(guess) < number:
        print "Too Small"
        score = score - 10
```

Notice that I'm casting the `guess` variable to an integer in order to get the comparisons right.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code had indentation issue
2. data/integer read from the command line had to be converted into 'int' form
3. Use 'break' to exit from while loop when condition is met instead of 'quit()'

Here is the working code :

```
import random
score = 1000
print "Welcome to this number guessing game!"
number = random.randint(1, 50)
print "number is", number
while True:
    guess = int(raw_input("Guess the number between 1 and 50: "))
    print "number is", guess
    if (guess == number):
        print "You got it right!"
        print "Your score was:", score
        break
    if (guess < number):
        print "Too Small"
        score = score - 10
    if (guess > number):
        print "Too Big"
        score = score - 10
```